# Show last digit only in os.time()

Tags: time, lua, modulus

I'm trying to code a function that prints something different every second.

Easiest way to do this (I think) is by checking if the integer is even or odd.

- On even numbers, it should print 'x'.
- On odd numbers, it should print 'y'.

My problem is that I cant figure out how to change the integer value of `os.time` to only show me the very last digit (only show 0 to 9) so I can easily implement this in my code.

This is what I have so far:

```
local seconds = os.time() --but only show last digit, e.g. 0 to 9

function changeStr()
    if (seconds % 2 == 0) then
        print("x")
    else
        print("y")
    end
end
```

Comment: Read the title, and then read the body of the question. Make them agree (or rather, what in the world does "even / odd" have to do with "last digits"?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to change the integer value of os.time to only show me **the very last digit (only show 0 to 9)**

Divide by 10 and take the remainder. That'll give you only the 10s place.

```
 seconds % 10
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a string containing the last digit of the time, try

```
string.sub(os.time(),-1)
```